# How to make children clicked when clicking parent

Tags: reactjs

How can I make children clicked when clicking parent?

My component is like this

```
const AllForms = ({ data }) => {
    const divclick = ()=>{
        // click all the buttons inside the div
    }
    const populateFormidButton = () => {
        return data.subs.map((i, index) => {
            return (
                <button key={index} type="submit" form={i.formId}></button>
            )
        })
    }
    return (
        <div onClick={divclick}>
            {populateFormidButton()}
        </div>
    )
}
export default AllForms
```

I want when I click the `div` all the buttons inside that div will be clicked too. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "the buttons clicked" ? If you would like to toggle a function on a button click, why don't toggle this function by clicking the div?

Comment: what happens when you click on a button ? just trigger what happens on click on button to a click on the div

Comment: @simon yes that what I want

Comment: @angrykiwi inside `divclick` run a `forEach` loop and call the `.submit()` method for each of the individual forms? if you are facing issues, plz let me know what type of react form your using, else a working stackblitz or similar

Comment: i'm using useFormik forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood the task correctly.

In this example I used `useRef` and `querySelectorAll("button")` and `click()`

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

const Form = ({ data }) => {
  const divReference = useRef(null);

  const divclick = () => {
    const buttonList = [...divReference.current.querySelectorAll("button")];
    buttonList.forEach(el=>el.click());
  };

  const populateFormidButton = () => {
    return data.subs.map((i, index) => {
      return (
        <button key={index} type="submit" form={i.formId}>
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={divReference}
      onClick={divclick}
    >
      {populateFormidButton()}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Comment: querySelectorAll("button") works. thanks